# Custom and Unmanaged User Model/Lagacy User Table

Tags: python, django, model, permissions, django-guardian

I am trying to make `django-guardian` work with my custom User model. The model is inherited from `AbstractUser` and also from `GuardianUserMixin`. Here is the `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractUser, GuardianUserMixin):

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
```

The problem I am facing is when I am checking permissions. For example here `request.user.has_perm(...)`

Here is the error message:

`ProgrammingError at /manageDb/mira/follow/14/
    relation "users_groups" does not exist
    LINE 1: ...sion"."group_id" = "auth_group"."id" ) INNER JOIN "users_gro...`

Traceback:

```
    File "/home/khajvah/Project/mira_website/manageDb/views.py" in delete
  486.             if request.user.has_perm('follow', follow_object):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in has_perm
  353.         return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in _user_has_perm
  281.             if backend.has_perm(user, perm, obj):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/guardian/backends.py" in has_perm
  89.         return check.has_perm(perm, obj)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/guardian/core.py" in has_perm
  54.         return perm in self.get_perms(obj)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/guardian/core.py" in get_perms
  110.                 perms = list(set(chain(user_perms, group_perms)))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  162.         self._fetch_all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  965.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  1217.             for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  794.             results = self.execute_sql(MULTI)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  658.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

The problem seems to be that `guardian` is making query on a table `users_groups`, which doesn't exist, instead, it is called `auth_groups`, which is created by `django.auth`. So the problem comes down to specifying the user group model in `guardian`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a hacky solution. What was `guardian` doing is expecting a `ManyToMany` relationship with `User` and `auth_group`. `AbstractUser` does this by default but since I have manually given `managed = False` and also a `db_table`, Django wasn't creating the relationship when migrating, so I created a intermediate model for the relationship and here is how a part of my `model.py` looks like:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, GuardianUserMixin):

    username=models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=123)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    email=models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=125)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=128)

    is_staff = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
    is_active = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD='username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = UserManager()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'

class GroupUser(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users_groups'
```

The key thing is to have the group table to have the correct name. I.e. guardian is waiting for `userTableName_groups`.